# How to handle/escape Python Comments in FLEX lexer?

Tags: python, regex, comments, lexer

Can anybody guide me how I can handle/escape Python Comments in FLEX lexer, so that tokens don't get generate for the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need a rule looking like this:

```
"#".*  ;
```

This will make your lexer to skip the comments and not generate any tokens for it.

Comment: without the ; probably if it is flex

Comment: ';' is necessary here. After the regex there must be some code - usually it's just `return A_TOKEN` or a whole code block in curly brackets, ';' serves like a NOP (no operation) here.